# Conversion to Word, pdf of Report Server Project (rdl) does not wrap correctly

Tags: c#, pdf, reporting-services, ms-word

I am working with report server project in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 for the first time ever and I am having some problems. Report is rdl and it was made by someone else I have no idea how and when. I have to customize it to work differently. I have only VS 2008 so I imported report and it looked ok in viewer and also converted to word.
After I made some changes, added a row group and one new text box (i have no idea how to add new child row group, that option is unavailable for some reason) report is working fine and it looks fine in report Preview. But now it looks awful converted to word. In word it has no right margin and it goes off the page on the right side. It's seems by adding new row group wrapping is all twisted. That does not happen in Preview.
Did anyone had similar problem? What could be the issue here and how to resolve it? Is it possible to make row grow just vertically but not horizontally?

[image]

This is how it looks like exported to Word file (notice how right margin is gone and wrapping is bad)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to help without attaching some screen shots.

From my experience converting to PDF is usually ok (blank pages can be because of linking too much bands to each other).

Converting to DOC/word is other story and a screen shot of the problem might help

Comment: Added a picture. I also made arrows that point from field to row group. Does it help?

Comment: picture of the "bad" output might help